# Downsample number of colors

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I'd like to plot a 3D dataset with colors. That is, each point has an associated rgb color. When I use [`scatter3`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter3.html) for this task, the plotting process is veeeeery slow. I have searched for alternative options and came up with the function [`plot3k`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/9519-color-coded-3d-scatterplot/content/plot3k.m) from FileExchange:

This function however is only able to plot each point's color by referring to some colormap via an index and does not take the rgb values directly. Also, it repeatedly uses `plot3` to do its plotting which also gets very slow when the colormap is too large.

So, I was wondering:

Is there a function to downsample the number of colors? I.e., I pass a N x 3 RGB-Array to the function and the function returns indices and a new array `A`, where `size(A,1) < N` and `A(indices,:)` are the new approximated colors.

Comment: Are you sure the slowness has to do with the colors, and not just the number of points? Can you give some example code, how you did this with `scatter3`?

Comment: I am pretty sure, the runtime has to do with the number of colors in plot3k. However, in scatter3 the number of points is the important factor. Maybe there was a confusion? To run scatter3 for a pointcloud "pcl" where the first three columns are x,y,z and columns 4 to 6 is RGB I used: scatter3(pcl(:,1), pcl(:,2), pcl(:,3), 4, pcl(:,4:6)

Comment: Ok, I can confirm that. For 100,000 points scatter3 needs 20.7 seconds if each point has a different color, and 1.29 seconds if they all have the same color. Strange...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is such a function in core Matlab: [`rgb2ind`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rgb2ind.html). Its purpose is to approximate truecolor images by indexed images, so we have to fiddle around a bit to make it work.

I assume that `xyz` is an `N x 3` array of coordinates and `rgb` is an `N x 3` array of colors. If all the colors are different,

```
scatter3(xyz(:,1), xyz(:,2), xyz(:,3), 4, rgb)
```

takes about 21 seconds for N = 100000 (on my machine).

If `ncol` is the number of different colors used for approximation, then this does the trick:

```
% convert colors from 0–1 double format to 0–255 uint8 format
rgb = uint8(floor(rgb * (256 - eps)));
% give the color array the form of a truecolor image (N x 1 x 3)
rgb = permute(rgb, [1 3 2]);
% reduce the number of colors
[ind, map] = rgb2ind(rgb, ncol, 'nodither');
```

The result is a sequence of integer color indices `ind` into the color map `map`. The `nodither` option is necessary because our `rgb` is not really an image and therefore spatial error diffusion doesn't make sense here. The data can now be plotted using

```
scatter3(xyz(:,1), xyz(:,2), xyz(:,3), 4, ind)
colormap(map)
caxis([0 ncol] - 0.5)    % ensure the correct 1:1 mapping
```

For ncols = 100, color conversion and plotting together take about 1.4 seconds, a speed-up by a factor 15!

`rgb2ind` does minimum variance quantization in RGB-space, meaning that it only takes into account numeric similarity in its approximation, but not visual similarity. It should be possible to improve results by using another color space for approximation, for example [CIE *L*a*b**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lab_color_space#CIELAB).

Comment: I played around a bit with the same function but did not get it to work properly. Thanks for showing a working solution! :)